# how to get the variable from an any() function

Tags: python, any

I am looking to get the list_select variable that meets the criteria and do an append in the next line.

How can I make this available in the *list_select.append(dupe)* line?

```
if any(list_select in dupe for list_select in pattern_dict):
   list_select.append(dupe)
```

Comment: Can you show an example? Maybe you should just write an ordinary `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't with `any`, which just returns a boolean. Use a generator expression instead:

```
gen = (x for x in pattern_dict if x in dupe)
list_select = next(gen, None)
if list_select is not None:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `any` function is supposed to return a boolean, so if you want the slightly different behaviour of returning the first match, write a function with that behaviour:

```py
def first(seq):
    return next(iter(seq), None)
```

Usage:

```py
>>> first( i for i in range(10) if i**2 > 10 )
4
>>> first( c for c in 'Hello, world!' if c.islower() )
'e'
>>> first( i for i in range(10) if i == 100 ) is None
True
```

To use in your example, you would write something like:

```py
list_select = first( x for x in pattern_dict if x in dupe )
if list_select is not None:
    list_select.append(dupe)
```

---

If you are using Python 3.8 or later, the dreaded ["walrus" operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) allows for a more direct solution:

```py
if any((list_select := x) in dupe for x in pattern_dict):
    list_select.append(dupe)
```

This situation happens to be [one of the motivating examples](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target) for introducing the walrus operator.